# Hysteresis Losses in High voltage Power Lines

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Do long-distance power lines exhibit hysteresis losses? These lines are mostly aluminum but they do have a core of steel for added strength.

Comment: I haven't heard of hysteresis losses in power lines. As I understand it the main loss is Joule heating.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this question, it is clear, precise and to the point. It may get more attention in the https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ but it is quite appropriate here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are hysteresis losses, although not always significant.  From the [Wikipedia Aluminium-conductor steel-reinforced cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium-conductor_steel-reinforced_cable#Hysteresis_loss) page:

> The resistances of ASCR conductors are tabulated for different
> conductor designs by the manufacturer at DC and AC frequency assuming
> specific operating temperatures. The reasons that resistance changes
> with frequency are largely due to the skin effect, the proximity
> effect, and hysteresis loss.
>
> [...]
>
> Hysteresis in an ACSR conductor is due to the atomic dipoles in the
> steel core changing direction due to induction from the 60 or 50 Hertz
> AC current in the conductor. Hysteresis losses in ACSR are undesirable
> and can be minimized by using an even number of aluminium layers in
> the conductor. Due to the cancelling effect of the magnetic field from
> the opposing lay (right-hand and left-hand) conductors for two
> aluminium layers there is significantly less hysteresis loss in the
> steel core than there would be for one or three aluminium layers where
> the magnetic field does not cancel out.
>
> The hysteresis effect is negligible on ACSR conductors with even
> numbers of aluminium layers and so it is not considered in these
> cases. For ACSR conductors with an odd number of aluminium layers
> however, a magnetization factor is used to accurately calculate the AC
> resistance. The correction method for single-layer ACSR is different
> than that used for three-layer conductors. Due to applying the
> magnetization factor, a conductor with an odd number of layers has an
> AC resistance slightly higher than an equivalent conductor with an
> even number of layers.
>
> Due to higher hysteresis losses in the steel and associated heating of
> the core, an odd-layer design will have a lower ampacity rating (up to
> a 10% de-rate) than an equivalent even-layer design.
>
> All standard ACSR conductors smaller than Partridge (135.2 mm2 {266.8
> kcmil} 26/7 Aluminium/Steel) have only one layer due to their small
> diameters so the hysteresis losses cannot be avoided.